# Struts ActionForm Lost from Request scope

Tags: java, struts, actionform

I've taken over maintenance of a 10-year-old Struts 1.2 application.  (It's way too complicated and proprietary to post.)

The application uses a couple of ActionForms which were formerly stored in the session. 
Because the latest change request requires that we open multiple ActionForms at the same time, I've changed the configuration of the ActionForm from session scope to request scope with struts-config.

This change breaks some custom tag code that looks for the ActionForm within the PageContext object.  (And it may break other functionality that we have not been able to test because of  this error.)

The code is looking for the ActionForm with 
  TagUtils.getRealValueFromBean

I've tried tweaking parameters in this call to specify the request scope and tried looking within the request object's attributes but the ActionForm is not there!  Java code within the JSP shows no such attribute within the Request object.
(I've heard that a refresh event can create a new ActionForm but here there's no ActionForm whatsoever within the Request object.
And yet, at the bottom of the Action that retrieves the object from the database, the ActionForm is present within the Request object.

I created a small test application with an ActionForm that can be configured in either session or request scope, but the retrieval of the ActionForm from Request works fine!

Any idea of where/how to track down how the ActionForm is getting clobbered?

Or else how to support multiple instances of ActionForm while keeping `scope=session`?

Comment: what did you mean when you said: «*open multiple `ActionForm`'s at the same time*»? A same request using multiple instances of the same `ActionForm`?

Comment: In this application, the ActionForm maps to a domain object.  The application used to limit the user to opening a single domain object at a time but users requested the ability to have more than one open at a time.

Comment: How about a *list* of objects for each user/`ActionForm`? Assuming that remains the `scope=session`.

Comment: The first strategy I tried when implementing this change was keeping track of a List (actually a Map but same idea) of domain objects for the user.  I was able to access the correct domain object for each page, but the ActionForm always contained values for the most-recently opened object. At save time, the application plumbing was mixed up as to which domain object went with the ActionForm and I got errors.   Is there an easy way to keep a separate ActionForm per page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

Assuming `scope="session"` and `Foo` as my domain class:

```java
public class Foo {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Then:

- In the `ActionForm`:

  ```java
  private static Map map = new HashMap();

  public Foo getFoo(String page) {
      if (!map.containsKey(page)) {
          map.put(page, new Foo());
      }
      return (Foo) map.get(page);
  }

  public void setFoo(String page, Foo foo) {
      map.put(page, foo);
  }
  ```
- Input JSP

  ```html
  <html:text property="foo(page1).name" />
  ```

  Where `page1` is an arbitrary name, e.g.: the name of your current page. `foo(page1).name` is the name of the property, so that it is automatically populated by Struts when it is sent to the server.
- Output JSP

  - With **E**xpression **L**anguage (EL):

    ```html
    ${TestForm.getFoo('page1').name}
    ```
  - With Struts:

    ```html
    <bean:write name="TestForm" property="foo(page1).name" />
    ```

  Where `TestForm` is the name of my `ActionForm` (defined in the *`struts-config.xml`* file).

Comment: Still working on trying this idea.  The application is very complicated any many layers of code (e.g., custom tags) expect a bean with the old type of information. Hopefully, we can get this to work. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: It took a while to implement this but it looks like the approach is working for us.  Thanks, Paul!